# how to make sur that Jboss is well installed and configured?

Tags: jboss7.x

I m using eclipse indigo and i installed the Jboss Server earlier.i though that every thing is fine;
But when i make a right clik on a JSP page for exemple ,there is no "Deploy" ,and if i what to deploy the whole project..the same thing i can't do it because the is no "Deploy" option.
iand if i ighone all that and do a "Run As" --> "Run on a server" i get a http 404 error saying the requested ressource is not available.
 i have Jboss in my eclipse ,is there any why to know that Jboss is well insatlled??
Thank you

Comment: this is the first error i found on the console " java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080"

Comment: It seems that 8080 port is in use by another application. You have to close that application or configure JBoss to work on another port. In order to understand which application is using this port you can run "netstat -aon" command and then look up the application by PID.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check whether JBoss 7 is running is to access native management interface.

Usually it's bound to 9999 port.

In order to verify the port look for port attribute of management native interface socket binding in standalone.xml (standalone-full.xml or whatever configuration you are using)

For localhost it would be:

`http://localhost:9999`

Another way to check JBoss 7 status is to use management console.

Usually it's bound to 9990 port.

In order to verify the port look for port attribute of management HTTP interface socket binding in standalone.xml (standalone-full.xml or whatever configuration you are using).

For localhost it would be:

`http://localhost:9999`

Additionally, you can check the so called marker files.

Just go to deployments directory and look for .deployed file (if the file exists it means that your application is successfully deployed).

You can read more about deployment descriptors at:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment